# How we Assign TabId to Tab Content div from Model Value In asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

This following code for Rendering Tabs

```
<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs customTabs">
                    @foreach (var p in ViewBag.ProductMenu)
                    {
                        if (p.Visible)
                        {
                            if (p.Id == 1)
                            {
                                <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="@("#" + p.TabId)">@p.Name</a></li>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="@("#" +  p.TabId)">@p.Name</a></li>
                            }
                        }
                    }
                </ul>
```

Above code is well doing work for rendering tabs. Now i want to assign TabId which is coming from model to assign tab-content which is following

```
 <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
                    <div id="quickDesp" class="tab-pane active">
                        @Html.Raw(Model.QuickDesription)
                    </div>
                    <div id="mainDesp" class="tab-pane">
                        @Html.Raw(Model.MainDescription)
                    </div>
                    <div id="features" class="tab-pane">
                        @Html.Raw(Model.Feathures)
                    </div>
                    <div id="softwares" class="tab-pane">
                        @Html.Raw(Model.Softwares)
                    </div>
                    <div id="specification" class="tab-pane">
                        @Html.Raw(Model.Specification)
                    </div>
                    <div id="suport" class="tab-pane">
                        @Html.Raw(Model.Support)
                    </div>

                </div>
```

how i can assign dynamically TabId to our div like this one

```
<div id="suport" class="tab-pane">
                        @Html.Raw(Model.Support)
                    </div>
```

id comes from model but i cant understand how i can handle any one can help me

Comment: try this  `id=@Model.YourColumnName`

Comment: But id comes form another table.

Comment: Then you have to create viewModel class and bind same to the view